# Sometimes Socket data not received properly in android studio

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, join

I am new to the java as well as Android.
Data write is working ok as i seen it on the modsim terminal(modbus protocol terminal), query is also valid as the response is generated through terminal but most of the time data is not received in the socket.

Here is the expected work flow of the code.

after pressing read button writing thread is being called after some delay like 500ms read thread is called and after some delay for ensuring reading is complete process the data if valid query is received or not. what i observe is in the received buffer data is 0 but rec_count showing the value.
and chk_data is being called.

I have tried the handler postdelayed but some error generated as i call thread there.
Also m'i using the CounDowntimer correctly?

Please suggest the good approach to delay the function call
I have skip the some code routine as it gets the unnecessary attention.

here is the code,

```
write_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            builder.setMessage("Wait...");
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            //Creating dialog box
             final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle("Data Writing!");
            alert.show();
            ((Myapplication) getApplication()).setData_array( 10,1);
            data_length = write_multiple_reg(output_array);
            new Thread(new Write_Thread()).start();
            start_timer3();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 500ms
                    alert.cancel();
                }
            }, 5000);

        }
    });

    read_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            builder.setMessage("Wait...");
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            //Creating dialog box
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle("Data Read!");
            alert.show();

            data_length = holding_register(output_array);
            new Thread(new Write_Thread()).start();
            start_timer1();
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 500ms
                    alert.cancel();
                    cancel_timer1();
                    start_timer2();

                }
            }, 5000);

        }

    });


}

void start_timer1(){

    timer1 = new CountDownTimer(300,10) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            new Thread(new Read_Thread()).start();
            //cancel_timer1();
        }
    };
    timer1.start();
}

void cancel_timer1(){
    if(timer1 != null)
    {
        timer1.cancel();
    }
}

void start_timer2(){

    timer2 = new CountDownTimer(1000,10) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    chk_data();
                }
            },500);

            //cancel_timer2();
        }
    };
    timer2.start();
}

void cancel_timer2(){
    if(timer2 != null)
    {
        timer2.cancel();
    }
}

void start_timer3(){

    timer3 = new CountDownTimer(500,10) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            new Thread(new Read_Thread()).start();
            start_timer2();
            //cancel_timer3();
        }
    };
    timer3.start();
}

void cancel_timer3(){
    if(timer3 != null)
    {
        timer3.cancel();
    }
}

class Thread1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            output =  socket.getOutputStream();
            input = socket.getInputStream();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //tvMessage.setText("Connected\n");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Write_Thread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            output.write(output_array,0,data_length);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

class Read_Thread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                rec_count = input.read(input_array);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}

void chk_data()
{
    if(rec_count!=0) {
        rec_crc = crc_generate(input_array, (byte) (rec_count - 2));
        rec_crc &= 0x0000FFFF;
        rec_high_crc = (byte) (rec_crc >> 8);
        rec_low_crc = (byte) rec_crc;

        if ((rec_high_crc == input_array[rec_count - 1]) && (rec_low_crc == input_array[rec_count - 2])) {
            if (input_array[1] == 0x03)        //holding register response
            {
                    copy_input_data(rec_count);
                    if(cnv_data[10]==2)
                    {
                        //write successful message
                        cnv_data[10]=0;
                        builder1.setMessage("Successful");
                        builder1.setCancelable(true);
                        builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        builder1.show();
                    }
                    else if(cnv_data[10]==1)
                    {
                        //write failed message
                        cnv_data[10]=0;
                        builder1.setMessage("Failed");
                        builder1.setCancelable(true);
                        builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialogInterface.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        builder1.show();
                    }
            }
            if(input_array[1] == 0x10)
            {
                data_length = holding_register(output_array);
                new Thread(new Write_Thread()).start();
                start_timer3();

            }
        } else {
            builder1.setMessage("Failed");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder1.show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        builder1.setMessage("Failed");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder1.show();
    }
    rec_count=0;
    cancel_timer2();

}
```

Comment: What are you using all those timers for? I don't think you will be able to get a very good successful transaction rate if you keep that approach. Android is not particularly good for real-time tasks, and you are asking too much out of its time-keeping capabilities. Besides, you should not need that many tasks for a Modbus transaction, you can go with just one: write the query and go into a loop to wait until the device sends its answer. Do you have any particular reason not to be using any of the existing Modbus libraries for Java?

Comment: Im using the timer to ensure the thread is completed its execution, other than that there is no need to wait. I just come to know using join() i can ensure the thread is finished but im not sure how to use it in android.Also im not aware of existing modbus java libraries, as you mention im going to look for it, but my routines are working fine as it sends the correct modbus querry.

Comment: Looks like i need to know how to ensure the thread task is complete before calling next thread. I found the join() but there is no example i came across for android platform. Is anyone have experienced in it?\